# Why there is no Addon.Ocr.Tesseract and Addon.Recorder in addon panel in G1ANT software?

Tags: g1ant

Even it shows my software is up to date.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install them from the Marketplace. Go to Tools -> Marketplace and select the appropriate addons you want. 
Here are some screenshots:[image: Marketplace option] [image: Recording Addon][image: Recorder Addon][image: Tesseract OCR Addon]